# Managed Platform Event Trigger not working after Sandbox Refresh

Tags: managed-package, sandbox-refresh, platform-event

We have the following scenario:

We created a managed package that contains a Platform Event and an Apex Trigger subscribed to it and installed it at a customer Org. In the Customer Production Org we have a custom Process Builder Flow and a custom apex trigger subscribed to the packaged event. So in Production it's all working fine, however upon Sandbox Refresh (Full Copy, from Production) we experienced difficulties.

The two apex triggers (managed and custom) are not listed as subscribers of the managed event anymore (Setup > Develop > Platform Events > MyEvent__e > Subscriptions).

After reading up on the issue it seems to be a [SF Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000FmO9QAK) that has not been addressed yet (see also [this question](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000l9Z2QAI)). There is a [similar StackExchange question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/206577/sandbox-trigger-that-subscribes-to-platform-event-never-executes/206578?noredirect=1#comment340999_206578) that comes up with a workaround. By simply editing and saving the custom trigger we were able to fix this but only for the **custom** trigger. We have no way of recompiling the **managed** trigger in the same way.

[image]

So far we have tried these different approaches:

- recompiling all apex classes
- re-install of the same package version
- install of a higher package version (patch version)

But we could not solve this issue. A complete uninstall and reinstall in the SB is not possible due to many customizations to the packaged components in the customer Org.

Any workarounds or suggestions are highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be related to this know issue. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000FmO9QAK&title=platform-events-trigger-not-getting-auto-subscribed-when-creating-refreshing-a-sandbox If it is the case you will have to re-install the package in sandbox.

Comment: @Ranga that issue was already linked in my question ;-) Also we tried the simple reinstall and it did not work. As I said to completely uninstall the package is also not possible due to customizations and to be honest performing this every time a sandbox is refreshed is not sustainable.

Comment: Apologies Robert. Didn't read the question properly! :( Nothing much we could do other than asking Salesforce to fix the issue I guess. If you have premier support with Salesforce, raise a case (if you haven't already done) and escalate it with your Salesforce Account manager to make sure that they fix the issue as soon as possible.